# Вывод записей из Mysql в виде блоков

Tags: вёрстка, php, html, css, mysql

Делаю сайт с новостной лентой. И вид этой ленты сейчас довольно популярен – отображение новостей в виде блоков-"кирпичиков" (картинка + описание).

Я организовал следующую разметку:
Ряд div'ов одной ширины и высоты с CSS(float:left;) и в конце этой строчки br с CSS(clear:both;).

Заказчик вдруг обнаружил для себя, что ему требуется так называемый бесконечный скроллинг. Вопрос назрел, и весьма серьезный:

Как мне оптимизировать мою верстку под динамичный вывод из Mysql? Я уже в течение трех дней прыгаю с форума на форум и вот решил написать сюда. Пожалуйста, вдохновите :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `display: inline-block`, чтобы блочные элементы следовали друг за другом, и при изменении ширины родителя они заполняли эту ширину собой (почти так же, как float). После этого добавление новостей будет уже не таким геморным.